# DB_NAME error message. Getting same error even after changing the script

Tags: php, database-connection

I'm trying to workout a login script which has a login form and a set of required files, among them db_connection.php (below)

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "LoginSystem");
define("DB_PASS", "secret");
define("DB_NAME", "login2015");

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die("Database connection failed: " . 
     mysqli_connect_error() . 
     " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
);
}
?>
```

when trying to run index.php I get the following error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"login2015"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\includes\db_connection.php on line 5

changing the name of the DB_NAME constant or replacing double quotes by single quotes does nothing. What's more. Even **changing the DB_NAME constant to something entirely different yields the exact same error, including "'login2015'" as part of the error message even though the constant is no longer defined as that**.

Might it have something to do with php.ini configuration cache or something of the sort? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can't reproduce this error.

Comment: What's your PHP version? Also there possibly could be some \n\r problems. You can try to erase the whole string and just retype it.

Comment: @Axalix php version 5.6.3, tried erasing the whole string, even without a constant defined I'm getting the exact same error.

Comment: The suggested duplicate question says nothing about why I am getting the same error even after deleting the constant, nor is it clear by the script or the answers of the duplicate question why I am getting this error even though the syntax of the script has no problems